# When index merging is possible with Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, indexing, composite-index

I am trying to enable a variety of queries in an app using Firestore, and I recently had to add several composite indexes to allow them to work. But I am noticing a lot of overlap in the queries and wondering if it's possible to merge some of them by relying on [index merging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#taking_advantage_of_index_merging).

My app needs to filter, sort, and paginate data from Firestore, so I added indexes like this to make them all work:

```js
[
  // allows sorting
  [
    ["price", "desc"],
    ["term", "asc"]
  ],
  [
    ["price", "asc"],
    ["term", "asc"]
  ],
  [
    ["gName", "asc"],
    ["term", "asc"],
    ["title", "desc"]
  ],
  [
    ["term", "asc"],
    ["gName", "asc"],
    ["title", "asc"]
  ],
  // allows filtering (and sorting)
  [
    ["gId", "asc"],
    ["price", "desc"],
    ["term", "asc"]
  ],
  [
    ["gId", "asc"],
    ["price", "asc"],
    ["term", "asc"]
  ],
  [
    ["gId", "asc"],
    ["gName", "asc"],
    ["term", "asc"],
    ["title", "asc"]
  ],
  [
    ["gId", "asc"],
    ["term", "asc"],
    ["gName", "asc"],
    ["title", "asc"]
  ],
]
```

The first four enabled various sorting options to work, but when I needed to be able to filter the data (by using where("gId", "in", [...]) queries), while keeping the sorting options I'd already got working, I found I needed to add four more indexes using the same values as before, but just starting with additional "gId" constraint.

There seems to be a lot of overlap between these indexes. I was wondering if some of them could be merged to reduce the number of needed indexes. The example on the docs page wasn't clear to me regarding what fields can and can't be merged in my situation.

How can I consolidate these indexes to leverage index merging while still allowing all of my queries to work? Or is this even possible in my case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation on [Queries supported by single-field indexes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#queries_supported_by_single-field_indexes):

> Using these automatically created single-field indexes, you can run simple queries like the following:
>
> ```
> const stateQuery = citiesRef.where("state", "==", "CA");
> const populationQuery = citiesRef.where("population", "<", 100000);
> const nameQuery = citiesRef.where("name", ">=", "San Francisco");
> ```
>
> You can also create in and compound equality (==) queries:
>
> ```
> citiesRef.where('country', 'in', ["USA", "Japan", "China"])
>
> // Compound equality queries
> citiesRef.where("state", "==", "CO").where("name", "==", "Denver")
> citiesRef.where("country", "==", "USA")
>         .where("capital", "==", false)
>         .where("state", "==", "CA")
>         .where("population", "==", 860000)
> ```
>
> If you need to run a compound query that uses a range comparison (<, <=, >, or >=) or if you need to sort by a different field, you must create a composite index for that query.

So Firestore **is** able to use multiple single-field indexes for a query, but only in the cases where the query only uses equality condition on those fields.

For queries that don't meet these conditions (for example any multi-field query where you *have to* specify an `orderBy` clause), a dedicated composite index is required.

---

Firestore doesn't look for non-overlapping indexes, but for a set indexes that match a prefix/suffix (depending of where you start considering) of the required fields until it meets an ordering clause or range condition.

If you're interested I recommend checking out my video from a couple of years ago on [how to implement geoqueries on NoSQL databases](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mx1mMdHBi5Q) or Alfred's even older video on [zigzag merge join in Datastore](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ofhEyDBpngM) (the older name for what is now called "index merging").

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I wasn't understanding the process behind how Firestore does its indexing, and this (and your talk on geoqueries and rewatching Todd Kerpelman's videos) helped. In my case, my queries are all primarily chains of orderBy clauses (for sorting by various fields where field values are often the same), so my discrete indexes indeed seem necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you were asked to create an index for a particular query, then no other index you had previously would be able to cover that case.  The direction of the sort matters when your query requires ordering. One index can't cover both sort directions (that's why you're asked to create one in both cases). And it ends up being very common for apps to create indexes for each possible combination of filters and ordering like this.  It's unavoidable in order for Firestore to continue to perform queries at massive scale with constant performance guarantees.

You can test this for yourself by removing an index and trying all of your necessary queries to see if they still work.  If they all still work, then you don't need the index anymore.  Since we can't see all your queries, then we really don't know if your indexes are necessary.

Comment: "There is no such thing as index merging in Firestore." Actually, there is. From [Taking advantage of index merging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#taking_advantage_of_index_merging): "Although Cloud Firestore uses an index for every query, it does not necessarily require one index per query. For queries with multiple equality (==) clauses and, optionally, an orderBy clause, Cloud Firestore can re-use existing indexes. **Cloud Firestore can merge the indexes for simple equality filters to build the composite indexes needed for larger equality queries.**"